# sql server cmdlet (sqlps) and remote server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using `sqlps` powershell module to get some data from my local database. My code is something like this

```
PS C:\> Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking
PS SQLSERVER:\> cd "SQL\myMachineName\..."
```

It works correctly, but sometimes I need to connect to a remote server running SQL server, so I use `Enter-PSSession`. Is this the correct way or can I somehow map that server under local `SQLSERVER:\SQL` directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PowerShell provider for SQL server can be used to connect to a remote SQL server without PowerShell remoting. For example, at the SQLSERVER: drive, you can change the location to a different SQL Server using

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> cd "SQL\remoteMachineName\SQLInstanceName"
```